# How to append a list in list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I have data like
`data = [('101339602', 's', 6), ('101339602', 'm', 7), ('101339602', 'xl', 3), ('101339602', 'l', 3), ('109302806', 'm', 4)]`

Now, I want to show grouped data(based on id) like below using list comprehension

```
[
    {
        '101339602': [{ 'size_worn': 's', 'total': 6}, { 'size_worn': 'm', 'total': 7}, { 'size_worn': 'xl', 'total': 3}, { 'size_worn': 'l', 'total': 3}]
    },
    {
        '109302806': [{'size_worn': 'm', 'total': 4}]
    }
]
```

I've written following code but don't know how to append data if id is same

```
[{x[0]: [{"size_worn": x[1], "total": x[2]}]}
  for x in _request_initialized_per_size_no_chart]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the below

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = [('101339602', 's', 6), ('101339602', 'm', 7), ('101339602', 'xl', 3), ('101339602', 'l', 3), ('109302806', 'm', 4)]

result = defaultdict(list)
for d in data:
  result[d[0]].append({'size_worn':d[1],'total':d[2]})
result = [{k:v} for k,v in result.items()]
print(result)
```

output

```
[{'101339602': [{'size_worn': 's', 'total': 6}, {'size_worn': 'm', 'total': 7}, {'size_worn': 'xl', 'total': 3}, {'size_worn': 'l', 'total': 3}]}, {'109302806': [{'size_worn': 'm', 'total': 4}]}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I need output wrapped in square brackets, like below

[
    {
        '101339602': [{ 'size_worn': 's', 'total': 6}, { 'size_worn': 'm', 'total': 7}, { 'size_worn': 'xl', 'total': 3}, { 'size_worn': 'l', 'total': 3}]
    },
    {
        '109302806': [{'size_worn': 'm', 'total': 4}]
    }
]

There should be list of dictionaries

Comment: @SaqibRajpoot Got it.. Code was modified.

Comment: Glad I managed to help. Please accept the answer.